# SalesForce1 Custom Action

Tags: salesforce1-app, force.com

I have an SalesForce org where I only have two full SalesForce users, and the rest of the users are Force.com.

I have created an action, that opens a custom VisualForce page. I have added this to the SalesForce1 Actions section on the page layout. The button is visible and works fine for the two full users, but the Force.com users it is not visible.

What am I missing, do I need to give the users a specific permission on the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I did not give the force.com users access to the VisualForce page that is launched by the button! So the button was hidden as there was no access to the page.